# Which is more important for phd? university or supervisor?

Tags: phd, advisor

If you ought to choose a Phd program in scientific/engineering field: a top 10 university without good supervisor and almost self-guiding or a top 200 with expert in the field?

Comment: See: [What's More Important in Choosing a PhD Program - Advisor or Institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/whats-more-important-in-choosing-a-phd-program-advisor-or-institution?rq=1)

Comment: The works done during Ph.D. is more important than any of these two parameters.

Comment: Also see: [I've been admitted to multiple PhD programs, how should I choose between them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/66926/11365)

Comment: In a general sense, the University, as a prestigious university will host high-impact faculty. But, not always nor in all fields!