# Is the university really important for picking a PhD?

Tags: phd, university

I want to study for a PhD in robotics. The research laboratory is a renowned one but the associated university is not. In fact, the laboratory is part of a research institute.

Do you think that would be a desadvantage knowing that I intend to work in the industry after the Phd and not in academics?

Comment: This will likely depend on the country and company you will work for. One would hope that they would care only for your skills (which probably depend more on the laboratory than the university) but in reality it is not so easy...

Comment: What's more important is the supervisor, who will ensure you'll finish and end up with high quality publications.  Let's say you join a top university but never finish or someone does not have a good record.    Then you will have none of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [University rank/stature - How much does it affect one's career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d) and/or [What's more important in choosing a PhD program, advisor or institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/44440/whats-more-important-in-choosing-a-phd-program-advisor-or-institution)

Answer (score 4):

The university means something, but the reputation of the professor you will work with means much more. There are some top professors at "modest" universities. I assume that if the research lab is renowned it is for the faculty, not the overall institution of which it is a part.

And many people here seem to want to suggest, mistakenly, that some given university is not "renowned". Not every place is Oxbridge or MIT/Harvard, but plenty of great research comes out of those other "lesser" places. And even the "renowned" places may not excel in every field.